# QGIS crashes too frequently to work

Tags: qgis, mac

I am running QGIS 2.18.7 on Mac OS (10.11.6).
The application crashes frequently. I usually only manage a few minutes work (while saving all the time) before it crashes.
I recently upgraded to this version as the last version was crashing too often... glad that helped!
There doesn't seem to be any common thing that causes this. Sometimes it crashes when I try to edit a shapefile, sometimes when I open a raster layer, sometimes when I zoom.... endless number of things.
I have tried setting up a new workspace, and keeping it trim and none of my open files are exceptionally large.
I have tried uninstalling all the plugins.

I have also checked other threads and noticed a few people having these issues, and the only thing that helped anybody was to follow the advice on the install page to rename or move the location of 'Qt4 developer components'. However I have no idea what these are.. or where to find them!! I search in finder and look in the usual places but no sign of these items.

Comment: What are the "threads" that you have reviewed?

Comment: From which version did you upgrade? What data sources do you have? Does it happen too if you create a new project, with new datasets?

Comment: @AndreJ i upgraded from 2.18.2 to 2.18.7. I am happy to say that the LTS version 2.14.14 is stable and i have experienced exactly 0 problems. however there are a few features that i prefer in the new version.

Comment: Working on Windows, I got frequent crashes after upgrading from 2.18.4 to 2.18.5, as well as newer versions. So I went back to 2.18.4 and work happily with it. Unfortunately, I could not narrow down the reasons for crashing.

Comment: My data consists of a few raster base layers (.tif c.60mb) and vectors of geology and contours as well as point files for structural data. i tried creating new projects with the absolute minimum of layers but this made no difference. the last crash before giving up and re-installing the LTS version i had a new project with just raster layer.

Comment: @PolyGeo the threads related to anything i could find on QGIS crashing on mac.

Comment: My QGIS 2.18 was crashing before it even started, till I heeded this suggestion in the readme: “If you have an old QGIS.app in your Applications folder, trash it before installing QGIS 2.16. Old files may not be deleted by the installer, which may cause problems for QGIS 2.16.” (The readme wasn’t updated since 2.16, this is actually for 2.18.) So I opened my Applications folder in Finder, dragged QGIS to the Trash, and then installed all four installers in the QGIS dmg file I downloaded from KyngChaos.

Comment: thanks @AhmedFasih but yes i did all this. i also removed all other traces of QGIS before re-install. this is my usual protocol for problem software.